# how does facebook instant games quota works?

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-games

facebook instant game allows developers to publish 1 to 2 games per week , we are a company we have our business verified account and we are 3 developers , my question is :
these 2 games per week limit is it per developer account or per entire business account ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is per entire business account.